# Weblogic 12c JPA 2.1 spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, weblogic

I want to deploy a spring boot application to weblogic 12c (12.1.2).

The application using latest spring boot libraries. I try to using `prefer-web-inf-classes` but I run out of luck.

If I try to using `prefer-webinf-classes` I got (my application is using validation api 1.1.0.Final):

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

If I try to using this configuration in web.xml:

```
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.xmlbeans.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.joda.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

I got `hibernate weblogic "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider"` exception from validator.

How can I solve this? (upgrade weblogic is not an option)

Thanks

Comment: Can you start your server with -verbose:class and check the stack trace in the .out file and see if it gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my late answer. My final solution:

1. add weblogic.xml into your war with these content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <wls:weblogic-web-app
       xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
       http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
       http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
   <wls:container-descriptor>
       <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
   </wls:container-descriptor>
   </wls:weblogic-web-app>
   ```
2. Create ear (It's important) and add weblogic-application.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application
       http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">
   <prefer-application-packages>
       <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
       <package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>
       <package-name>org.joda.*</package-name>
       <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
       <package-name>org.jboss.*</package-name>
       <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
   </prefer-application-packages>
   </weblogic-application>
   ```

This is work for me...

Comment: do you perhaps have a sample project available on github of some sort?

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue with Spring Boot and WebLogic 12c with error 
`org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`

I was getting this error only if I was using any of validation annotations.

Solved by adding this to weblogic.xml:

```
    <prefer-application-resources>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! There are many advices how to resolve this problem, but this and only this worked. You saved my day, I'd upvote hundred times if I could.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there is a classloading conflict between the API and the implementation (eclipse.jpa.PersistenceProvider).

However, the reason for such conflict is yet to explain, since the 'prefer-application-packages' is supposed to tell the container to use what comes within the application package (i.e. both the API and implementation).

A workaround that worked for me in WLS **12.2.1** is as follows :

1. Exclude the dependency to the JAP2 API :

   > ```
   > <dependency>  
   >   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   >   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   >   <exclusions>
   >       <exclusion>
   >           <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   >           <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
   >       </exclusion>
   >   </exclusions>
   > </dependency>
   > ```
2. Make sure your the 'prefer-application-packages' in weblogic.xml does **not** include javax.persistence.* (but should include javax.validation.* and org.hibernate.*)

Using this workaround, you are relying on the JPA2 implementation of the container..

Beware, thought, that this might be confusing if versions are different since behaviour might differ between unit tests (using JPA2 implementation that comes with Spring Boot : hibernate-jpa) and tests in container (using whatever JPA implementation WebLogic provides: likely eclipse JPA Provider).

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. I'm not using eclipselink. I think weblogic provide this library, but I'm not understand prefer web inf or application packages why not override wls provided library....

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to remove `javax.persistence.*`

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late to answer you question I guess but it sounds like you are using a new interface and old implementation. This happens sometimes when you deploy to a container and not using class-path filtering for instance. In turn you will use an older implementation provided by the container. The behavior is very random depending on what gets loaded when. Hope this helps you in right direction or anyone else having similar problem.